# How do i speed up this looping of pixels in PIL

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, python-imaging-library

I want to treat the `r` and `g` channel of a pixel and convert it from `0 <-> 255` to `-1 <-> 1`, then rotate `(r, g)` around `(0,0)` using the angle stored in `rotations[i]`. This is how I normally do it with regular for loops, but since the images I work with are ~4k*4k in dimensions, this takes a long time, and I would love to speed this up. I have little knowledge about parallelization, etc., but any resources would be helpful. I've tried libraries like `joblib` and `multiprocessing`, but I'm feeling as though I've made some fundamental mistake in those implementations usually resulting in some pickle error.

```py
c = math.cos(rotations[i])
s = math.sin(rotations[i])
pixels = texture_.load()
for X in range(width):
    for Y in range(height):
        x = (pixels[X, Y][0]/255 -.5)*2
        y = (pixels[X, Y][1]/255 -.5)*2
        z = pixels[X, Y][2]
        x_ = x*c-y*s
        y_ = x*s+y*c
        x_ = 255*(x_/2+.5)
        y_ = 255*(y_/2+.5)
        pixels[X, Y] = (math.floor(x_), math.floor(y_), z)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `numpy`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with python and NumPy in general, but as far as I know, I thought that NumPy arrays are also slow in looping like standard arrays? If not could you link some resources?

Comment: Yes, for looping you would get the same behavior. However, if you vectorize the computation (as a matrix computation) it will be much faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numpy` to vectorize the computation and compute all individual elements at once in a matrix style computation.

Try something like this:

```py
import numpy as np

pixels = np.array(pixels)  # Assuming shape of (width, length, 3)

x = 2 * (pixels[:, :, 0]/255 - 0.5)
y = 2 * (pixels[:, :, 1]/255 - 0.5)
z = pixels[:, :, 2]
x_ = x * c - y * s
y_ = x * s + y * c
x_ = 255 * (x_ / 2 + .5)
y_ = 255 * (y_ / 2 + .5)
pixels[:, :, 0] = np.floor(x_)
pixels[:, :, 1] = np.floor(y_)
pixels[:, :, 2] = z
```

Comment: It works if i use the texture as the input for np.array()